# Getting Google Maps to lead the road through a path from Google Assistant

Tags: google-maps, accessibility, google-assistant, voice-command, maps

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

I was able to use the interface between Google Assistant and the Camera app by saying "Take a photo", and, Google Assistant takes a photo (after opening the camera app and launching a timer).

Now, I would like to have the same sort of functionality between Google Assistant and Google Maps.

I would like to tell Google Assistant (show me the path from town A to town B in maps, passing from town C, and talk the corresponding directions to me).

Google Maps should open up and do that.

However, I was unable to make this behavior work in Google Assistant/ Google Maps.

When will this be implemented?

How can I get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: While multiple stops is already possible in Google Maps, I don't think Google Assistant supports it yet.